# Dictionary sorting by order in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to create a script that will take a dictionary of unique keys, and sort by their similar listed string values. Each value is listed in order of preference from an imported csv. I am new to python and am having some trouble in conceptualizing this, but so far I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
myDict = { 's1' : ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 
           's2' : ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], 
           's3' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
           's4' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 
           's5' : ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'], 
           's6' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
           's7' : ['b', 'a', 'a', 'd'],
           's8' : ['c', 'b', 'd', 'a']}

#next I created a new dictionary where the values are listed keys to be filled
newDict = { 'a' : [], 'b' : [], 'c': [], 'd' : [] }

#updating newDict by 1st listed value in myDict
for j in range(1):
    for x in myDict.keys():
        newDict[myDict[x][j]].append(x)

#result
newDict = { 'a' : ['s1', 's3', 's5'], 'b': ['s7'], 'c' : ['s2', 's4', 's6', 's8'], 'd': [] }
```

Next, I would like to loop where it references the listed values in myDict and fill in the newDict keys so that each key has two values, balancing out by their 'ordered' preference.

This would mean that it would have to reference the second or third listed value from myDict key and update its values throughout to find a balance. For example:

```
#intended final newDict values
newDict = { 'a' : ['s1', 's5'], 'b': ['s7', 's3'], 'c' : ['s4', 's6'], 'd': ['s2', 's8'] }
```

Apologies for any mistakes and thanks for the insight

Comment: I would not bother looping in range 1 just use indexing

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would you suggest to do that?

Comment: if you just want the 0 index simply use  `myDict[x][0]` , also just iterate over the dict, you don't need .keys(). Why does `a` have `s1` and `s5` together?

Comment: I don't understand the question. (Is there a question?) How do you get the output `{'a' : ['s1','s5'], 'b': ['s7','s3'], 'c': ['s4', 's6'], 'd': ['s2','s8']}`?

Comment: @Rawing That's what OP is trying to figure out. He wants to "smooth" `newDict` so that each each value has the same length.

Comment: @senshin: But then where does the `s3` in `b` come from? And the `['s2', 's8']` in `d`?

Comment: @Rawing Senshin is correct. In the end I would like to iterate over the newDict and balance it out so that each key has 2 values based on their order in myDict

Comment: @Rawing I don't think it's fully specified, but the notion is that `'b'` is the second entry in `myDict['s3']`, so `'s3'` is moved from `'a'` to `'b'` (since that's the "second-most-preferred" thing for `'s3'`).

Comment: @user2909469 Can you describe, step-by-step and in detail, how you get from your `#result` version of `newDict` to your intended final `newDict`?

Comment: @Senshin : the 's3' in 'b' and 'd': ['s2', 's8'] comes from reference myDict original value order and balancing it out from c and a that has more than 2 values

Comment: You could use a common key to sort

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible implementation of the result you desire

```
myDict = { 's1' : ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 
           's2' : ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], 
           's3' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
           's4' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 
           's5' : ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'], 
           's6' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
           's7' : ['b', 'a', 'a', 'd'],
           's8' : ['c', 'b', 'd', 'a']}

options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
newDict = {option: [] for option in options}
for key, value in myDict.items():
    newDict[value[0]].append(key)

# balance out the dictionary
desired_length = 2
while True:
    for key, value in newDict.items():
        if len(value) > desired_length:
            popped = value.pop()
            new_index = myDict[popped].index(key) + 1
            new_key = myDict[popped][new_index]
            print('Move {} from {} to {}'.format(popped, key, new_key))
            newDict[new_key].append(popped)
    if all(len(value) == desired_length for value in newDict.values()):
        break
print(newDict)
```

Output:

```
Move s4 from c to a
Move s4 from a to b
Move s6 from c to a
Move s6 from a to b
Move s6 from b to d
Move s5 from a to b
Move s5 from b to d
{'d': ['s6', 's5'], 'b': ['s7', 's4'], 'c': ['s8', 's2'], 'a': ['s3', 's1']}
```

This is not "optimal" in any sense (though I don't even know what you would consider optimal), nor is it even guaranteed to return a useful result (it's conceivable that we could run out of a/b/c/d options for a given s# and thus walk off the end of a list), nor is it deterministic (since order of iteration for dictionaries can vary from run to run), but perhaps it will give you some idea of where to start, and where you need to understand your goal better.

Comment: this has no rhyme or reason though so not really a useful way to distribute the items

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I agree. I'm more hoping that OP can use this as a springboard from which to figure out something better.

Comment: @senshin thank you very much, this helps greatly. The key to this is essentially optimization, making sure that best balance is achieved. Any other methods you may suggest in balancing out a dictionary like this?

Comment: @user2909469 _You_ need to figure out how you want it balanced. What are you trying to optimize? Are you trying to minimize the number of moves made? Or are you weighting things so that something at its 4th priority is significantly worse than something at its 2nd priority? Once you figure that out, you will have an easier time of balancing your dictionary.

Comment: @sensin I am trying to weight things so that in the end the key gets the highest possible weighted value, which seems to align with your idea that a key getting a value at its 4th priority is worse than its 2nd. Any thoughts on building this in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to solving your problem by refusing to fill a list in `newDict` with more than two items. It is probably not quite optimal, since it awards the "first choice" spots based on a first-come-first-served basis, without considering which second choices are easier to fill than others. It does however consider all first place picks first, then all second place picks, then third, etc.

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

myDict = { 's1' : ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 
           's2' : ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'], 
           's3' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
           's4' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 
           's5' : ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'], 
           's6' : ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
           's7' : ['b', 'a', 'a', 'd'],
           's8' : ['c', 'b', 'd', 'a']}

newDict = defaultdict(list)

to_assign = deque(myDict.items())          # Start with a queue of all of myDict's items
while to_assign:
    key, value = to_assign.popleft()       # Take an item off the queue
    if len(newDict[value[0]]) < 2:         # See if its first pick is available
        newDict[value[0]].append(key)      # If so, add it to the result
    else:                                  # Otherwise, put the item on the
        to_assign.append((key, value[1:])) # end of the queue with its first pick removed
```